# Using "this" in jquery, but not sure how to implement it

Tags: jquery

I want to incorporate "this" in this code:

```
$(".nds").on('click', function () {
 $("div.accordion-header").switchClass("active");
 $('div.accordion-header').next('div.accordion-content').slideDown(750);
});
```

because right now when ".nds" is clicked, all elements of the class "accordion-header" open. Or is there any other way, besides this, to achieve the same?

Edit with (hopefully) relevant HTMl code:

```
        <div id ="floating">
        <div class="nd3 nds" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"><a href="#SG16">16</a></div>
        <div class="nd2 nds" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"><a href="#SG17">17</a></div>
        <div class="nd1 nds" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"><a href="#SG18">18</a></div>

        <div id="floating-button" data-toggle="tooltip">
            <span class="ham"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="accordion">
            <!-- ############ SG01 ############ -->
            <div class="group" id="SG01">
                <div class="accordion-header"></div>
                <div class="accordion-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show us the HTML

Comment: if your .nds not related to your accordions = then this will not help. in click event $(this) will be every html item with class .nds, so we not sure we understand you.

Comment: @MaxDeepfield only the one that is clicked... not _all_

Comment: just to clarify, .nds is a button that when clicked will open a panel. The problem right now is that it will open all the panels. For example, we have 15 different nds buttons and each of them has a corresponding panel. As of right now clicking any nds button will open all of them. I just want the corresponding one to open.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: what exactly is .nds ? place your .nds in same div as accordion, so you can do $(this).parent().find('.whatever').slideClasses(). this will work if you have separate parent div for every .nds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the accordion is the parent of the target element that you've bound the click to, you could do something like this:

```
 $(".nds").on('click', function () {
     var header = $(this).closest('.accordion-header'),
        content = header.next('.accordion-content');

    header.switchClass('active');
    content.slideDown(750);
});
```

It depends on where those accordion divs are in the DOM relative to the target, but the general idea is that you would "walk" the DOM starting with `$(this)` --i.e. the event target-- until you find those nodes.

Have a look at the following methods in case .`closest()` isn't what you need:

```
.find(), .siblings(), .parent()
```

Use the appropriate combination of those methods (you can chain them together) to get from $(this) to the elements you wish to manipulate.

A few more notes that aren't specific to your question, but will help you nonetheless. If you are going to use the same selector more than once in a function, save it to a variable. That way, jQuery only has to "walk" the DOM to find it once. Otherwise, you are making jQuery go and look for it again. (Across a large code base, stuff like that tends to add up and drag on performance.)

Also, you can probably select just by the class ('.accordion-header') as opposed to div.accordion-header. More efficient selectors also helps with performance.

UPDATE AFTER OP POSTS MARKUP:

It looks like you are attempting to use some pre-made component like a bootstrap widget. Thus you shouldn't have to manually code the slide toggle.

That being said, I *think* you are trying to do something like this:

```
 $(".nds").on('click', function () {
     var targId = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
     $(targId).find('.accordion-header').toggleClass('active');
     $(targId).find('.accordion-content').slideToggle(750);     
 });
```

It seems like this was intended for the user to click on the link, and not the "nds" div that wraps it. However, since you're binding to `$('.nds')` I'm writing my code the same way.

Comment: I tried .find(), .parent() and .silblings(), none of them work. So it is probably safe to assume that they are not "related". I would post the html code, but it is massive and I don't really know the part that would be relevant to this question :/

Comment: @Vroryn we just need to see enough of the HTML that we can figure out where the element with a class of "nds" lives in relation to the accordion-header and accordion-content that you want to affect.

Comment: I updated my post, not sure if this was what you were looking for?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap for these accordions? It looks similar to Bootstrap markup. Off the top of my head, I'm guessing that clicking  <a href="#SG16">16</a> is supposed to affect whatever div has an id of SG16. If it's bootstrap, or some other out-of-the-box accordion component, you shouldn't have to manually code the slideUp /slideDown

Comment: I am not sure if the original owner used it, I am just trying to expand the code

Comment: @Vroryn check my updated answer. I have to go, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nds a").on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // remove active class from all accordion headers
   $('.accordion-header').removeClass('active');

   // the key here is to grab the target from the href of the anchor
   var target = $(this).attr('href');
   // then make changes inside the target only 
   $(target)
      .find('.accordion-header')
      .addClass("active") 
      .next('div.accordion-content')
      .slideDown(750);
});
```